# Sending XAMPP emails through gmail

Tags: email, xampp

I've surfed the web for solutions for a few hours now, tried MANY suggestions. This is my final hope. I'm using windows 7 with the newest version of XAMPP. Running only Apache and MYSQl.

This is my test script:

```
<form action="testemail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

testemail.php:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

This is sendmail.ini

[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
; smtp port (normally 25)
smtp_port=587 (I also tried 465 and 25)
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com 
auth_password=mypass
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
hostname=
```

this is php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

My ISP is blocking port 25 so i cant do it locally. Really, if anyone is sending xampp mails through gmail right now id like to hear anything you did to make it happen.